# trying to create an elevation map but getting errors

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Im trying to make an elevation map using np.meshgrid and np.linspace but I get this error: object cannot be interpreted as an integer on this line of code:

```
[x,y]=np.meshgrid(np.linspace(np.min(Long),np.max(Long),np.sqrt(pts)),np.linspace(np.min(Lat),np.max(Lat),np.sqrt(pts)))
```

I'm not sure how to get around this as I am new to python
this is my code

```
data = np.loadtxt('Documents/location.txt') 
Long = data[:,0]
Lat = data[:,1]
Elev = data[:,2]

pts=1000000

[x,y]=np.meshgrid(np.linspace(np.min(Long),np.max(Long),np.sqrt(pts)),np.linspace(np.min(Lat),np.max(Lat),np.sqrt(pts)))

z = griddata((Long, Lat), Elev, (x, y), method='linear')
x = np.matrix.flatten(x); #Gridded longitude
y = np.matrix.flatten(y); #Gridded latitude
z = np.matrix.flatten(z); #Gridded elevation'''
```

Comment: Might be because np.sqrt() typecasts to float, you can fix this by putting int() around it. Edit: np.sqrt().astype(int) might be better

Comment: absolute star - that was it!   thank you